# apache karaf faild to load web bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf

I downloaded the apache karaf 4.x and installed the 'war' feature and the karaf-doc bundle using following commands:

```
feature:install war
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.karaf/manual/4.0.0/war
```

but karaf failed to load that web bundle:

```
2016-01-17 17:16:36,167 | ERROR | pool-4-thread-1  | RegisterWebAppVisitorWC          | 64 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 3.2.6 | Registration exception. Skipping.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2279)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1501)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1844)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:937)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:194)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)[:1.7.0_45]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.loadClass(RegisterWebAppVisitorHS.java:244)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.visit(RegisterWebAppVisitorWC.java:261)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.model.WebApp.accept(WebApp.java:652)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.register(WebAppPublisher.java:237)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:182)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher$WebAppDependencyListener.addingService(WebAppPublisher.java:135)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:317)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:261)[karaf-org.osgi.core.jar:]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppPublisher.publish(WebAppPublisher.java:101)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver.deploy(WebObserver.java:213)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebObserver$1.doStart(WebObserver.java:175)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.SimpleExtension.start(SimpleExtension.java:58)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.extender.AbstractExtender$1.run(AbstractExtender.java:266)[64:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war:3.2.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)[:1.7.0_45]
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The supplementary questions at the end are not appropriate for stackoverflow. They are primarily opinion-based. Please remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Karaf doc bundle in 4.0.0 actually had an issue if you do:

```
feature:install war
bundle:install -s mvn:org.apache.karaf/manual/4.0.3/war
```

it's working right away. 
Just navigate to

```
http://localhost:8181/karaf-doc/
```

you're able to see the deployed applications via:

```
karaf@root()> web:list
ID | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
97 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /karaf-doc      | Apache Karaf :: Manual (4.0.3)
```

I doubt that OSGi is dying, actually the other way round, but that is a biased opinion.
Apache Karaf and ServiceMix based on it are ready for production, don't know about Virgo.

Comment: after switched to 4.0.3, it works now, but if I click any link on the home page, it goes to a wrong location without the application context root(karaf-doc).

Comment: might be an issue of the manual bundle, please open an issue for it at the jira for apache karaf. The manual can also be found at karaf.apache.org

Comment: If I  manually add context root, I can see it... for me karaf is buggy.

Comment: please ask with some more details at either the karaf mailinglist or the ops4j mailinglist, with a concrete explanation of your issue